# Write into the file in kernel mode and get '\00' symbols instead of " " space

Tags: android, c, linux, linux-kernel

I write into the file like this

```
vfs_write(filp, prefix, strlen(prefix), &pos);
    pos = pos + strlen(prefix);
```

but in the file besides my data I see "\00" symbols. They take all available space from the end of my data to the end of each line.

> ff ff ff ff ff ff a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 81 00 08 34\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
>   \0008 06 00 01 08 00 06 04 00 01 a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00

something like this.

How can i write into the file only my data and nothing more?

Comment: I'm guessing `vfs_write` updates `pos` automatically, so you shouldn't need to increment it yourself.

Comment: Perhaps your `prefix` points to an array that only exists in the kernel address space? It must be an userspace pointer (i.e. point to an address in the current process' address space, not a pointer to some kernel-only visible memory); see [fs/read-write.c:vfs_write()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/read_write.c).